# Altair: formatting tooltip ordinal datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, altair

The output of my live tooltip example is:

[image]

Where the `x-axis` is formatted at `ordinal` dates; but the chart is also run through Streamlit, which appears to produce timestamps in milliseconds from the epoch. (Note: it appears Streamlit manipulates `ordinal` dates in some way. As such, I cannot reproduce an exact example, nor the exact tooltip output).

However, an example with millisecond code as the `x-axis` is as follows (I believe):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': range(20),
    'y': pd.date_range(end='2022-01-18', periods=20, freq='B').view(np.int64) / int(1e6)
})

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.X('x:O',
          axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep = 2, labelAngle=0),

),
    alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(values=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20])),
    alt.Color('y:Q'),
    tooltip=alt.Tooltip('y:O', title='Date')
)

chart.save('ex.html')
```

Is there a way to format the `y:O` to print out `%m %d, %Y` datetime format?

Comment: I looked for a way to convert the time series on the tooltip but couldn't find it, is it possible to add a display column? Specifically, I added the 'y2' column by doing only `pd.date_range()` and changed the tooltip specification as follows. `tooltip=alt.Tooltip('y2:T', title='Date')`

Answer (score 1):

If you were to first add a second y, say y2, to your dataframe that had the dates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'x': range(20),
'y': pd.date_range(end='2022-01-18', periods=20, freq='B').view(np.int64) / int(1e6),
'y2': pd.date_range(end='2022-01-18', periods=20, freq='B')
})
```

You would just have to change your alt.Tooltip field and field type:

```
tooltip=alt.Tooltip('y2:T', title='Date')
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think to try this. And changing the tooltip field type does make it look like I wanted. Unfortunately, the datetime is in milliseconds from epoch and changing the field type to ':T` puts my dates in 1969